# Map Multiple Spring MVC Applications to Root Servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have multiple Spring MVC applications I want to deploy to the same server but am having troubles doing so.

In my web.xml I map the dispatcher servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, if I have multiple applications on the same server, I get the following error when trying to deploy:

`0000003f webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp initializeStaticFileHandler SRVE0278E: Error while adding servlet mapping --> /*.`

If I change the mapping to `/test` it works, but of course I want the dispatcher servlet mapped for all requests.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

I *want* all my requests under the root URI (i.e. `http://<server>/<contextroot>/*`) but am running into problems when having multiple applications do this.

Comment: Do you have multiple Spring apps in 1 war, or each Spring app in it's own war? If it's the later, can you show all your web.xml configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have hit this error: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK18713

As recommended, either

- upgrade your app server or
- disable file serving

Comment: That seems to take care of it, even though I'm not running those versions of Websphere. Will continue to watch to see if that option has any other side effects, but I'm considered it an answer at this point. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting the same error with 8.5.5.0 version when I try to start an Eclipse RAP application. Any Idea?

Comment: I get the same error with WAS v8.5.5.6. Disabling file serving solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> If I change the mapping to /test it works, but of course I want the
>   dispatcher servlet mapped for all requests.

In this case, you should replace:

```
<url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
```

with

```
<url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Then all my URL requests would need to be under `/test`, no? Updated question for clarification.